# How to print all elements of an array in C after I enter all of them?

Tags: c, arrays

So I have this code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[9], number_of_elements;
    printf("Enter 10 numbers: \n");
    for (int i = 0; ((i < 10) && (a[i] != 0)); i++) {
        scanf_s("%d", &a[i]);
        if (a[i] == 0) {
            number_of_elements = i;
            break;
        }
        if (a[i] != 0) {
            number_of_elements = i + 1;
        }   
    }
    printf("There is %d elements.\n", number_of_elements);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I have to enter max 10 elements into an array, or stop entering when you enter 0, and after that I have to print all elements of that array and how many elements array have. I sorted all things except printing all elements of the array, can anyone help me how to do that?

Comment: You use another loop, up to how many elements you have... with a formatted printing...

Comment: "Enter 10 numbers:" , when you have only allocated space for 9 `int a[9]`. The result of that program will just be excessive amounts of sadness.

Comment: You have two big problems with the code you show: The first is that you want to enter ten elements into an array containing only nine elements. The second problem is the condition `a[i] != 0` where you use `a[i]` before it has been initialized (and therefore will haven an *indeterminate* value).

Comment: Where do I put that another loop?

Comment: @SvenB Think a little! If you want to do A followed by B, you would not do B first would you?

Answer (score 3):

You should use another for loop, like:

```
for(i=0;i<number_of_elements;i++)
{
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After implementing @rsp's code, I fixed my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {

    int a[10], number_of_elements;
    printf("Enter 10 numbers: \n");
    for (int i = 0; ((i < 10) && (a[i] != 0)); i++) {

        scanf_s("%d", &a[i]);
        if (a[i] == 0) {
            number_of_elements = i;
            break;
        }
        if (a[i] != 0) {

            number_of_elements = i + 1;

        }

    }
    for (int i = 0; i<number_of_elements; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\nThere are %d elements.\n", number_of_elements);
    return 0;
}
```

Tnx everyone for help and tnx @George for being so funny :)